# Collect data from different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented a basic TCP client and server. The client sends a command from an input stream. The server processes received message and replies to the client.

I would like to test my client-server solution in the following manner:

1. Create multiple client threads;
2. Each client thread will read commands from the file and send them to a server;
3. After a server's reply, each client must collect the reply to a list;

I would like to seek any code review and any suggestions (I would appreciate any examples) on how to collect a server replies to a list from each client thread. Currently, I am not able to collect all replies from all client threads in  `List<String> messages`

Class `Client` spawns a fixed number of `ClientTask`

```
public class Client {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
private File configs;
private InputStream inputStream;
private int port;
private String ip;


public Client(File file, InputStream inputStream) {
    this.configs = file;
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
    Map<String, Object> configs = ConfigLoader.loadXMLConfigsFromFile(file);
    this.port = (Integer) configs.get("port");
    this.ip = (String) configs.get("ip");
}

//
public void start(int numberOfThreads, List<String> messages) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        List<String> collectedServerReply = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        try {
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(
                    new ClientTask(port, ip)
                            .setInputStream(new FileInputStream("commands.txt"))
                            .setReplyListener(message -> {
                                //messages.add(message.receive().getMessage());
                                collectedServerReply.add(message.receive().getMessage());
                                //System.out.println("current stack size: " + messages.size());
                            }));
            clientThread.start();
            System.out.println("finished client thread");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred while reading from System.in. Exception: ", e);
        }
        messages.addAll(collectedServerReply);
    }
}
}
```

The Client class has a setter that accepts any instance that implements the ReplyListerner interface. The latter server as an abstraction to collect a reply data:

```
public interface ReplyListener {

    void onReply(Message message) throws IOException;
}
```

I cannot collect all server replies in the method `public void start(int numberOfThreads, List<String> messages)`. However, when I simply do the following:

```
 Thread clientThread = new Thread(
                        new ClientTask(port, ip)
                                .setInputStream(new FileInputStream("commands.txt"))
                                .setReplyListener(message -> {
                                    System.out.println(message.receive().toString());}));
```

I could see the appropriate server replies in my `System.in`

Where did I make a mistake and how can I achieve my goal of collecting server replies?

**EDIT:**

How do I use my implementations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<String> collectedMessages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerLauncher(new File("config.xml")));
    serverThread.setName("server_thread");
    serverThread.start();
    new Client(new File("config.xml"), new FileInputStream("commands.txt")).start(1, collectedMessages);
    System.out.println("Collected output ...");
    for (int i = 0; i < collectedMessages.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(collectedMessages.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have race conditions if you use a non-synchronized implementation of `List`.

Either explicitly synchronize:

```
synchronized(messages)
    messages.addAll(collectedServerReply);
}
```

or be sure to call your start function using a synchronized list, for instance `Vector`

EDIT - following yours. Make sure to wait for all your threads to finish before displaying your list.

```
clientThread.join();
```

Of course, do that in a second loop or you lose all advantage of multi-threading.

Comment: I call my client instance on synchronized list. Please see the edit.

Comment: I will let you know ASAP when I test my app with your suggestions =)